# Change the color of the Scroll Bar in "Map mode" - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide, settings, color-scheme

How can I change the color of Visual Studio's scroll bar when it's in map mode? This is picture of what it looks like for me right now.

[image]

Basically, I just need to make the colors transparent so they blend in with the background. This used to be part of [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d), and I remember you could change the colors in those settings. But in Visual Studio 2015 it's been built into the IDE and there's no obvious settings for the colors.

I am also using the [Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b) extension, but if the color setting is editable from there, I can't find it.

I know it's possible to change these colors because I've changed it before (my colors got reset recently). Does anyone know where these settings are?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The colors are changeable using the Color Theme Editor extension by changing the "Text Editor -> Overview" colors. Specifically "Text Editor -> Overview background -> Background" and "Text Editor -> Overview visible -> Background".

[image]

Comment: In VS 2015 you can change the colors under Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Overview background/Overview caret/Overview collapsed region/Overview visible.

Comment: @needfulthing Still true for VS 2017.